# ListBox's selected item number

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox that looks something like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item4</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Is there a way to see the array of the selected item? I plan to perform a specific action depending on the ListBoxItem[Number?].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property, or possibly the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx) property and the [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items.aspx) property. Or maybe the [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) property. Your question isn't very clear as to what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the all the details. I'm actually pulling the data from an XML file. When the user selects one of these items, I will update many TextBox controls that display the child elements of the selected item. To do this, I need to know the array number in order to specify the right path. I hope that made sense...

Comment: In that case, `SelectedItem` is what you want, if the ListBox items are connected to XML elements. If not, you can use the `SelectedIndex` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can access items of a list box using the array syntax using the following sample but take a note that there are more ways that were much easier around. I also prefer the existing answer above.

Add the following namespace below:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

Then try to write the following code.

```
EX
        ListBox x = new ListBox();
        ListBoxItem[] y = x.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<ListBoxItem>().ToArray();
        y[0].Content = "Foo";
```